# Execute javascript function in c#.net. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, javascript, function, call

I want to execute a javascript function in a c# code. Here is what i did:

```
string jscript = "$(function () { $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open'); });";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", jscript, true);
```

ive no idea what to do, i didnt understand how this method works

thanks :)

obs.: i just write "clientScript", but i dont know how it works

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

            $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

            var fancyboxInitOld = jQuery("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 370,
                modal: true

            });
            fancyboxInitOld.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));


        });
</script>
```

My C# code

```
try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch
        {
            string jscript = "$('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientScript", jscript, true);
            }
```

Comment: @marko: Please don't swear on SO. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/134069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`RegisterStartupScriptMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) instead:

```
string jscript = "$(function () { $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open'); });";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
  "clientScript", jscript, true);
```

I see you did this in your `catch` block already. `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is there to render client code for later use, for instance some functions.

Comment: RegisterStartupScriptMethod gets red :(

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string jscript = "$('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientScript", jscript, true);
```

Comment: RegisterStartupScriptMethod gets red

Comment: use **this** instead **Page** or **typeof(object)** instead **this.GetType()** could help?

Comment: are you getting serverside or javascript error with the above?